# Error C2327: not a type name, static, or enumerator - MSVC14 only

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a code that compiles fine in GCC 5.3, MSVC12 and clang 3.7. However, it does not in MSVC14. It somehow tries to use a member instead of a namespace, I really have no idea what's going on here.

```
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

namespace data
{
class Bar {};
}

struct Parent
{
    int data;
};

namespace other
{
struct Foo : public Parent
{
    void foo(data::Bar);
};
}

void other::Foo::foo(data::Bar) { }

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

results in

```
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -EHsc /Fddebug\bug.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\bug -I. -IE:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include -IE:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -IE:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015
main.cpp
..\bug\main.cpp(21): error C2327: 'Parent::data': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
```

Note that this is a Qt project and if I remove the include, it compiles OK. Basically if I change anything in this code, it compiles OK. For example this works:

```
namespace other
{
void Foo::foo(data::Bar) { }
}
```

If I rename the member variable data or namespace data it works too. However I can't make these changes in reality, the declaration is generated code by qmake and renaming the namespace is not an option.

Could this be a compiler bug? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line `21`:

```
void other::Foo::foo(data::Bar) { }
```

`data` is an ambiguous identifier as it can be:

- The data namespace.
- The data member variable of class `Parent`.
- One of the data functions defined in the `xutility` include near line `1484` (on a standard installation it is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xutility`). `xutility` is indirectly included by `#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>`.

It seems that removing any of the 3 makes the compiler solve the ambiguity. You do not have the issue with other compilers surely because you do not have data functions in the `xutility` header or even the `xutility` file does not exist for them.

To solve the ambiguity, replace line 21 by:

```
void other::Foo::foo(::data::Bar) { }
```

If there are other places later where you must solve the ambiguity use one of these, depending on the context:

- `::data`
- `Parent::data`
- `this->data`

Answer (score 1):

`data` is ambiguous, as `Parent` already has a member of that name, and the compiler tries to resolve its member `Bar` which isn't there, being a variable (think of it as object) instead of a class or namespace.

I recommend to rename the namespace to avoid ambiguity and confusion, e. g. using CamelCase (`Data`), as lower case names should be reserved for variables/instances/objects. If this isn't an option try accessing it via the global namespace:

```
void foo(::data::Bar);
```

Comment: I'm just confused why does this compile w/o the include? I'm still not convinced that this declaration in fact is ambiguous.

Comment: if removing the Qt include allows it to build, then Qt must provide a some declaration of data that causes the ambiguity, since you cannot change Qt, you need to use a different identifier in you code.

Comment: @nate OP said renaming the `data` namespace work. So it is the OP's declaration of `namespace data` which conflicts not one in Qt. My guess would be that the Qt include might change the compiler behavior.

Comment: The solution is NOT to rename `data` (neither the namespace nor the variable). What if the name collision occurs from included libraries? The C++ offers everything to solve ambiguity, so the solution is to solve the ambiguity. Use `::data`, `Parent::data` or `this->data` to explicit what you do.

Comment: There are many "solutions", and resolving the ambiguity by using scope resolution, or `this->` are likely better solutions than renaming the namespace. But the ambiguity is still the fault of Qt.It might something like using the identifier `data` in an anonymous namespace in the global namespace which then hides the `data` namespace when looked up from the global namespace.

Comment: @nate You were right :) It is coming from the Qt include. See my answer.